# Table "disappers" during XSL-FO to PDF conversion

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have the following mark-up for a table at the beginning of larger `XSL-FO` file:

```
<fo:table-and-caption xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" display-align="center">
    <fo:table border="1px" border-collapse="separate" border-color="#000000" border-spacing="2px" border-style="outset" border-width="1px" role="table" text-align="center">
        <fo:table-body end-indent="0pt" last-line-end-indent="0pt" role="tbody" start-indent="0pt" text-align="start" text-align-last="relative" text-indent="0pt">
            <fo:table-row role="tr">
                <fo:table-cell border="1px" border-style="inset" padding="1px" role="td">
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:inline font-family="comic sans ms,sans-serif" font-size="medium" role="span">Top Left</fo:inline>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border="1px" border-style="inset" padding="1px" role="td">
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:inline font-family="comic sans ms,sans-serif" font-size="medium" role="span">Top Right</fo:inline>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row role="tr">
                <fo:table-cell border="1px" border-style="inset" padding="1px" role="td">
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:inline font-family="comic sans ms,sans-serif" font-size="medium" role="span">Bottom Left</fo:inline>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border="1px" border-style="inset" padding="1px" role="td">
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:inline font-family="comic sans ms,sans-serif" font-size="medium" role="span">Bottom Right</fo:inline>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</fo:table-and-caption>
```

The overall setup is described in my [PDF report with embedded HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789541/pdf-report-with-embedded-html) question.

When our application transforms it to PDF using `Apache POF`, the table "*disappears*".  The rest of the file seems to be normally converted.

Is there anything wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html.  `fo:table-and-caption` is not supported.  That may be the cause of your problem.

Since you don't have a caption, and since it's not supported by FOP anyway, why not omit the `fo:table-and-caption` element?

Comment: I will try to find the matching template and remove it.  Worth the trial.

Comment: Yep. That seemed to be the issue. Thanks