# Embed HTML paragraphs in xsl-fo/fop

Tags: html, xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm currently considering using xsl-fo/fop to generate PDFs out of my Java web application. Parts of the content to be printed are "HTML fragments" (TinyMCE editor in web frontend) from different sources.

Is there a way to "embed" HTML into FOP?

I want to avoid an xslt transformation for individual paragraphs containing HTML fragments (the doc contains a lot of other content as well). 
The alternative is to create one HTML/XML document containing all the paragraphs and other content and then apply an xslt transformation over everything, but somehow I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Note: I also considered HTML to PDF engines (e.g. Prince) but they seem to be ludicrously expensive.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at iText (java library for pdf generation)?  It can convert HTML to PDF, but I have never used the feature, so don't know how good it is at that.

Comment: Yes, looked at iText but haven't tested it. iText with its new licensing model is a bit prohibitive though.

Comment: This is a related question I answered which contains some relevant information/pointers ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789541/pdf-report-with-embedded-html/32789843#32789843

Comment: @KevinBrown Thanks, quite useful, esp the css2pdf stylesheets mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, FOP's only valid input is an XSL-FO file** (or XML + XSLT producing XSL-FO, but that's just a convenience option as it's an external library that performs the transformation).

However, **you can use / adapt an existing xhtml to FO stylesheets**, like those provided by [AntennaHouse](https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/xml-to-xsl-fo-stylesheets/#tabs-923-0-2) and [RenderX](http://services.renderx.com/Content/tools/fo2html.html).

Besides, even if you say you don't want to do it, **writing an xhtml -> XSL-FO transformation is not a daunting task**; this is especially true if the input comes from TinyMCE, as you can configure it to allow only a limited subset of tags, which will require a small set of templates.

*(disclosure: I'm a FOP developer, though not very active nowadays)*

Comment: Thanks for the links to the XSLT templates, I might go that way. 
By the way, as FOP feels a bit dated, do you have any other suggestions? Currently I'm using JasperReports but that doesn't scale well for complex documents.

Comment: @Thomas Why do you think it is dated? It had a new release last month :-) (to clarify my disclosure: _I_ have not been very active in the latest years, other developers worked on FOP _a lot_)

Comment: I know, but it's been around for ages (not a bad thing) and nowadays people talk a lot about HTML+CSS3. Having said that I think FOP allows a much better control over the outcome and is mature.